# Using LEFT combined with CHARINDEX giving error while extracting a substring from a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, charindex

I'm trying to use LEFT combined with CHARINDEX to extract a substring from a column in a table but its giving the following error

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

```
select name, left(name, charindex('\',name) - 1) as sub
from sys.servers
```

However, if i apply same on a single string using a variable it works..

```
declare @mytext varchar(max)
set @mytext = 'hello\world'
SET @MyText = LEFT(@MyText, CHARINDEX('\', @MyText) - 1)
print @mytext

O/P:
----
hello
```

Please let me know What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you want the query to return when there is no backslash?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `name` may not have a backslash.  This is easily fixed, but it depends on what you want as a result.  This gives the full name when there is no backslash:

```
select name,
       left(name, charindex('\', name + '\') - 1) as sub
from sys.servers;
```

The problem is that `charindex()` returns `0` when the value is not present -- and that is an error as the length for `left()`.

Comment: That would be name +'\'     ;)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use IIF for SQL 2012 + or Case to avoid the error when no '\' inside the text

```
declare @mytext varchar(max)
set @mytext = 'hello world'
SET @MyText = LEFT(@MyText, iif(CHARINDEX('\', @MyText)>0,CHARINDEX('\', @MyText) - 1,len(@mytext)))
print @mytext
```

CASE

```
SET @MyText = LEFT(@MyText,
CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('\', @MyText) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('\', @MyText) - 1
  ELSE LEN(@mytext)
END)

PRINT @mytext
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff & maSTA rHiA for your valuable answers. I cound'nt have figured out by myself why you get an error when there is no '\' in the text as i'm no expert in T SQL. Unfortunately, the instance i'm querying linked servers is running SQL 2008 so i can't use IIF function. I do however got around by using a case statement as you suggested.  
select name,
       case when name like '%\%' then left(name, charindex('\', name) - 1) 
       else name
       end as sub
from sys.servers

Answer (score 0):

When it can't find '\' in name it will give 0 so final result will be left(name,-1) which is invalid. So you need to write code in such a way that if there is -1 you need to treat that as 0. Below code fix that issue.

```
select name, left(name, ISNULL(NULLIF(charindex('\',name) - 1,-1),0)) as sub from sys.servers
```

Comment: If you need to return whole name if there is no '\' characters then you can use below code. `select name, left(name, ISNULL(NULLIF(charindex('\',name) - 1,-1),LEN(Name))) as sub
from sys.servers`